# стартовое окно в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

как настроить в Clion чтоб при входе в программу появлялось стартовое окно с списком проектов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По умолчанию идея открывает предыдущий проект. Необходимо убрать галочку Reopen last project on startup. тогда при старте отобразится меню выбора проекта

File -> Settings -> system settings 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]